# What about counter in python 2.5

Tags: python-2.5

> > > from collections import Counter
> > >       Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >         File "", line 1, in 
> > >       ImportError: cannot import name Counter

Comment: From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter): *New in Python 2.7*. So no, it is not available in 2.5.

Answer (score 0):

Counter is only supported in python2.7 and higher and is not available in earlier versions - Counter class got added into collections package in Python 2.7